# Extract Field Names and max lengths from a text file using C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a file that is a SQL Server result set saved as a text file.

Here is a sample of what the file looks like:

```
RWS_DMP_ID      RV1_DMP_NUM      CUS_NAME
3192            3957             THE ACME COMPANY                          
3192            3957             THE ACME COMPANY                          
3192            3957             THE ACME COMPANY
```

I want to create a C# program that reads this file and creates the following table of data:

```
     Field       MaxSize
     -----       -------
 RWS_DMP_ID  17 
RV1_DMP_NUM 17 
CUS_NAME    42
```

This is a list of the field names and their max length. The max length is the beginning of the field to the space right before the beginning of the next field.

By the way I don't care about code performance. This is seldom used file processing utility.

I solved this with the following code:

```
objFile = new StreamReader(strPath + strFileName);
            strLine = objFile.ReadLine();
            intLineCnt = 0;
            while (strLine != null)
            {
                intLineCnt++;

                if (intLineCnt <= 3)
                {                       
                    if (intLineCnt == 1)
                    {
                        strWords = SplitWords(strLine);
                        intNumberOfFields = strWords.Length;
                        foreach (char c in strLine)
                        {
                            if (bolNewField == true)
                            {
                                bolFieldEnd = false;
                                bolNewField = false;
                            }
                            if (bolFieldEnd == false)
                            {
                                if (c == ' ')
                                {
                                    bolFieldEnd = true;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (c != ' ')
                                {
                                    if (intFieldCnt < strWords.Length)
                                    {
                                        strProcessedData[intFieldCnt, 0] = strWords[intFieldCnt];
                                        strProcessedData[intFieldCnt, 1] = (intCharCnt - 1).ToString();
                                    }
                                    intFieldCnt++;
                                    intCharCnt = 1;
                                    bolNewField = true;
                                }
                            }
                            if (bolNewField == false)
                            {
                                intCharCnt++;
                            }
                        }
                        strProcessedData[intFieldCnt, 0] = strWords[intFieldCnt];
                        strProcessedData[intFieldCnt, 1] = intCharCnt.ToString();                               
                    }
                    else if (intLineCnt == 3)
                    {
                        intLine2Cnt= 0;
                        intTotalLength = 0;
                        while(intLine2Cnt < intNumberOfFields)
                        {
                            intSize = Convert.ToInt32(strProcessedData[intLine2Cnt, 1]);
                            if (intSize + intTotalLength > strLine.Length)
                            {
                                intSize = strLine.Length - intTotalLength;
                            }
                            strField = strLine.Substring(intTotalLength, intSize);
                            strField = strField.Trim();
                            strProcessedData[intLine2Cnt, intLineCnt - 1] = strField;
                            intTotalLength = intTotalLength + intSize + 1;                                

                            intLine2Cnt++;
                        }
                    }                       
                }
                strLine = objFile.ReadLine();
            }`enter code here`
```

I'm aware that this code is a complete hack job. I'm looking for a better way to solve this problem.

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

THanks

Comment: yes! you need to break down the code into 3 parts. 1st processes/loads the data into the structure haveing 3 property fileds which here are columns. Then you can use LINQ to group by things. Finally you have to save the result.

Comment: @Ankush I have a headache just thinking about breaking this up into three parts.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem. I thought you were doing aggregation. Let me think...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how memory efficient this is, but I think it's a bit cleaner (assuming your fields are tab-delimited):

```
var COL_DELIMITER = new[] { '\t' };
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(strPath + strFileName);

// read the field names from the first line
var fields = lines[0].Split(COL_DELIMITER, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

// get a 2-D array of the columns (excluding the header row)
string[][] columnsArray = lines.Skip(1).Select(l => l.Split(COL_DELIMITER)).ToArray();

// dictionary of columns with max length
var max = new Dictionary<string, int>(); 

// for each field, select all columns, and take the max string length
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    max.Add(field, columnsArray.Select(row => row[fields.IndexOf(field)]).Max(col => col.Trim().Length));
}

// output per requirment
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        max.Keys.Select(field => field + " " + max[field])
    ));
```

Comment: @FengYuan yep, granted slow, but speed isn't always the top consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void MaximumWidth(StreamReader reader)
    {
        string[] columns = null;
        int[]   maxWidth = null;

        string line;

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] cols = line.Split('\t');

            if (columns == null)
            {
                columns = cols;
                maxWidth = new int[cols.Length];
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
                {
                    int width = cols[i].Length;

                    if (maxWidth[i] < width)
                    {
                        maxWidth[i] = width;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: It's not tab delimited just a pile of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. The big takeaway is to use the IndexOf string function.

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String strFilePath;
            String strLine;
            Int32 intMaxLineSize;

            strFilePath = [File path and name];                            
            StreamReader objFile= null;

            objFile = new StreamReader(strFilePath);

            intMaxLineSize = File.ReadAllLines(strFilePath).Max(line => line.Length);

            //Get the first line
            strLine = objFile.ReadLine();

            GetFieldNameAndFieldLengh(strLine, intMaxLineSize);


            Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void GetFieldNameAndFieldLengh(String strLine, Int32 intMaxSize)
        {            
            Int32 x;            
            string[] fields = null;
            string[,] strFieldSizes = null;
            Int32 intFieldSize;

            fields = SplitWords(strLine);


            strFieldSizes = new String[fields.Length, 2];
            x = 0;

            foreach (string strField in fields)
            {
                if (x < fields.Length - 1)
                {
                    intFieldSize = strLine.IndexOf(fields[x + 1]) - strLine.IndexOf(fields[x]);                    
                }
                else
                {
                    intFieldSize = intMaxSize - strLine.IndexOf(fields[x]);
                }
                strFieldSizes[x, 0] = fields[x];
                strFieldSizes[x, 1] = intFieldSize.ToString();
                x++;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

        static string[] SplitWords(string s)
        {
            return Regex.Split(s, @"\W+");
        }
    }
```